# IntelliJ IDEA 11: Maven support not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.1 (Community Edition) on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) for Java and Scala Programming. Today I wanted to deal with Maven for the first time as I don't have any experience with build tools yet. But somehow the Maven support in IDEA doesn't seem to work at all.

Some facts:

- Maven 3.0.3 has been installed via MacPorts in `/Applications/MacPorts/share/java/maven3`
- the Maven plugin has been activated in the plugin manager
- Environment variables M2 and M2_HOME are set in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`

  - M2:      `/Applications/MacPorts/share/java/maven3/bin`
  - M2_HOME: `/Applications/MacPorts/share/java/maven3`
- Maven settings in IDEA are set to default
- Maven can be called from command line without any problems and works fine

If I try to open any pom.xml file via `File > Open Project`, nothing happens. Sometimes a small window with a progress bar opens for a second or two, obviously scanning some files, but always without any effect.

If I try to import an existing Maven project via `File > New Project > Import Project from External Model`, I only get to the window where I can define the project root directory and several Maven settings. When I click `Next`, nothing happens.

If I execute the Maven goal `mvn idea:idea` on a Maven project, I'm able to open it in IDEA.  After it has opened, a little green window appears in the upper right corner of IDEA, saying `Maven projects need to be imported` with two options: `Import changes` and `Enable Auto-Import`. It doesn't matter which one I choose, because nothing seems to happen. When I open the Maven Projects panel on the right side of IDEA it still says `There are no Maven projects to display`. If I try to add a Maven project from within this panel, either nothing happens as before or IDEA even completely refuses to open a pom.xml file in the `Select Path` window, because the OK button is greyed out.

I've checked the log files under `Help > Reveal Log in Finder` and they state some repeated exceptions which have to do with Maven. Here are two examples:

```
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.1 Build #IU-111.167 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.6.0_29 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: Apple Inc. 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: OpenProject 
2012-01-01 22:42:26,736 [3469999]  ERROR - #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Original exception:  
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: gnu.trove.TObjectHash; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1980179659817003644, local class serialVersionUID = -3461112548087185871
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:334)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy80.applyProfiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$3$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:94)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:132)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$3$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:91)
at $Proxy80.applyProfiles(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$8.execute(MavenServerManager.java:316)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$8.execute(MavenServerManager.java:313)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:313)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:389)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:537)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:484)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:445)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:416)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:60)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:131)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$100(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:28)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$9.run(MavenUtil.java:396)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$6.run(ApplicationImpl.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:137)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: gnu.trove.TObjectHash; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1980179659817003644, local class serialVersionUID = -3461112548087185871
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:291)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: gnu.trove.TObjectHash; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1980179659817003644, local class serialVersionUID = -3461112548087185871
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:306)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:288)
```

Next:

```
2012-01-01 21:45:33,856 [  57119]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - 1 paths checked, 0 mapped, 44 mks 
2012-01-01 21:46:16,240 [  99503]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - 7 paths checked, 0 mapped, 449 mks 
2012-01-01 21:47:17,728 [ 160991]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $OPTIONS$/dataSources.xml file is null 
2012-01-01 21:47:17,728 [ 160991]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $OPTIONS$/dataSources.xml 
2012-01-01 21:47:17,763 [ 161026]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dataSources.xml file is null 
2012-01-01 21:47:17,763 [ 161026]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dataSources.xml 
2012-01-01 21:47:17,867 [ 161130]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - 2 paths checked, 0 mapped, 153 mks 
2012-01-01 21:47:34,669 [ 177932]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/print.xml file is null 
2012-01-01 21:47:34,669 [ 177932]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/print.xml 
2012-01-01 21:47:56,928 [ 200191]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=com.intellij.ui.mac.MacFileChooserDialo gImpl$4$1@5f2d6fa7,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1325450876871] on apple.awt.CToolkit@4ad70ab0 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:313)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:389)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:537)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:484)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:445)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:416)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder.readMavenProjectTree(MavenProjectBuilder.java:198)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder.access$800(MavenProjectBuilder.java:44)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder$3.run(MavenProjectBuilder.java:179)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$8.run(MavenUtil.java:364)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:457)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$5.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:276)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:206)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:169)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:629)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$6.run(ApplicationImpl.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:137)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: gnu.trove.TObjectHash; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1980179659817003644, local class serialVersionUID = -3461112548087185871
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:334)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy80.applyProfiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$3$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:94)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:132)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$3$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:91)
at $Proxy80.applyProfiles(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$8.execute(MavenServerManager.java:316)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$8.execute(MavenServerManager.java:313)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `M2_HOME` environment variable [as described in the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160). If it doesn't help, check `idea.log` for exceptions (`Help` | `Reveal Log in Finder`). It's [worth filing a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) if there are any related exceptions in the log.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've set the environment variables as stated for OS X 10.6 and later, so this should not be the problem. I've checked the log files and found several exceptions that mention Maven. I've appended two of them to my initial posting. Do these help you?

Comment: I've just posted a [bug report on YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-79559) with more detailed exceptions. I hope it helps to fix this annoying bug soon.